# Excluding files if source has the same file name, but also destination has bad in the file name

Tags: windows, robocopy

So I have a source folder and a destination folder. I have setup my bat file to  copy files from one to the other if the destination does not have the file name. Now I want to set it up so that if the destination folder has a file, but with "bad" in the file name, no files that are similiar in the source do not get copied over to the destination folder. Here are 3 examples with the last example being what I am aiming for.

Examples:

Source:
Monday_8am.txt
Tuesday_9pm.txt

Destination:
"blank"

Action:
Monday_8am.txt (copied to destination)
Tuesday_9pm.txt (copied to destination)

Source:
Monday_8am.txt
Tuesday_9pm.txt

Destination:

Tuesday_9pm.txt

Action:
Monday_8am.txt (copied to destination)

Tuesday_9pm.txt (NOT copied to destination)

Source:
Monday_8am.txt
Tuesday_9pm.txt

Destination:

Tuesday_bad_9pm.txt

Monday_9pm.txt

Action:

"No action" (destination did not have "Tuesday_9pm.txt", but did have Tuesday_bad_9pm.txt)

Comment: Could I do an if then statement using ms dos and robocopy??

Comment: The task looks artificial and a working solution to solve the stated task can fail for many reasons in a real life situation.  We'd be wasting our time coding an exact solution for this task.

Comment: Robocopy does not run under "MS-DOS", it requires Windows (and runs in the command line of Windows)